Win11 WSL - Installing new distro never completes
Windows11 system, WSL2, have already been using 2 distros (Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04) for several years.
Today I opened Powershell and typed

wsl --install -d Ubuntu-24.04

A new terminal window opened and the only text is

Installing, this may take a few minutes...

and then nothing ever happens.  yes I am being patient but we are talking 30+ minutes.  I do not have slow internet so this is not the issue.  having trouble finding applicable solutions as most questions posted seem to be new WSL users.  any advice welcome.  thank you.

What version of the WSL kernel do you have? What version of Windows have you installed?  Are all required services for WSL started?  Are you able to launch your existing instances? Can you install it if you go directly to the Windows Store?

It turns out that the distro did indeed install.  When I start the instance it logs me in as root however.  added a user and set that user as default in wsl.conf file.  everything seems normal now except i do not get a login prompt when starting the distro.
